# How to show cursor in Unity "Play mode"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity, and have created a simple start menu with a play button that will load a game scene. However, when I click "Play" in Unity to test my game, I do not have a cursor. I have to hit escape for my cursor to appear. Do I need to create a script file to make my cursor visible, or how do I change this? I am unable to find anything in Unity forums. Googling the topic retrieves many "How to hide cursor" threads.

I have tried adding an empty object and adding a c# script to it that contains the following but I think I am missing a step?

```
public class CursorBehavior : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Cursor.visible=true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can help you.

[Cursor.visible](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-visible.html)

Comment: sorry, was editing question as you answered to include that I have tried adding empty object and attaching that script to it already

Comment: If I remember right, this script need to be attached to camera.